# (Linux) Swap fills up too late and oom_kill never activates, resulting in crash

Tags: linux, memory, crash

This is an issue I've had for so long. During normal high memory usage, swap fills up as needed and processes using up a lot of memory are properly killed once it gets too bad, but every now and then in certain cases (generally Firefox using up a lot of memory), this doesn't happen. Instead swap never fills up, and eventually RAM and swap quickly fill up to 100% and Linux crashes. What could be causing this and how can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did the crash create a system core dump ? If a system core dump was created, dump analysis might reveal what caused the OOM and why the system crashed.